# Как в ASP.NET MVC можно организовать страничное представление?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, веб-программирование

Допустим, получаю я 1000 строк из БД, которые нужно отобразить в представлении.

Однако, 1000 строк отображать на 1 странице- это не очень логичное решение, так как неудобно.

Как можно их отобразить в более удобном виде?

Например, разбить их на 10 страниц по 100 строк?

Может есть более красивый вариант?

Не помешал бы так же какой-нибудь пример.

Answer (score 2):

Я надеюсь, это ссылки будут полезны для вас.
Там есть хорошие примеры:

[Pagination-example-in-ASPNet-MVC 1](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Paging-Pagination-example-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

Comment: Надо бы чтобы в ответе было хоть немного кода. Иначе со временем ссылка может стать нерабочей и тем самым ваш ответ превратится в `null`. Если же вы не расположены давать развернутый ответ, то тогда лучше ограничится комментарием к вопросу с этой ссылкой.